# How to automatically assign a new number as a key in the dictionary whenever the user wants to add an item?

Tags: python, dictionary, auto-increment

For example, I have an empty dictionary called a shopping list. and it shall store keys such as #"1,2,3,4..." and the value should be a list that store the name and price of item. For some #reason I can only have 1 key in the shopping list only...

The code is below:

#Convenience store inventory of products with code number, item name, price and stock

```
 items = { 0:['black tea',500,20], 1:['red tea',500,1], 2:['milk 
 tea',500,0]}
 shopping_list = {}

 query = input("Enter the code number of the item you want to get: ")
 query = int(query)
 for i in items:
     if query == i:
          item = i
          print(items[item][0], "will cost you", "{:.2f}".format(items[item][1]/100),"dollars")
    
 #Temporary shopping list shall store item code, name and price from original list of product
 n=0
 buy_more = input("Do you wish to choose some more items? (Y or N) ")
 while buy_more.isdigit() and buy_more not in "Yy" and buy_more not in "Nn":
       print("Please enter (Y or N) only. ")
       buy_more = input("Do you wish to choose some more items? (Y or N) ")

       #loopback and let users to buy an additional item
       while buy_more in "Yy":
            shopping_list[n] = [items[item][0],items[item][1]]
            print("Nice! Please choose one more item.")
            buy_more = input("Do you wish to choose some more items? (Y or N) ")

       #Continue to the transaction process
       if buy_more in "Nn":
            print("Continue to transaction process. ")
            break
shopping_list[n] = [items[item][0],items[item][1]]
print(shopping_list).   `
```

Comment: why not use a `list` then and just append to it?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I'll try it later.

Comment: Dictionaries do not allow duplicates, increment with `n += 1` before [or after] every time you add a new item with *`shopping_list[n] = ...`* , or [ as hiroprotagonist suggested], just have a list instead of a dictionary - initiate with `shopping_list = []` and add with `shopping_list.append([items[item][0],items[item][1]])` ( btw are you aware that *`[items[item][0],items[item][1]]`* is the same as `items[item][:2]` since you just seem to want the 1st 2 values?)

Answer (score 0):

I optimised your code a bit, maybe it will help, here in the code since you asking for the item code as input I'm not incrementing it:

```
items = { 0:['black tea',500,20], 1:['red tea',500,1], 2:['milk tea',500,0]}
shopping_list = {}

#Temporary shopping list shall store item code, name and price from original list of product
buy_more='y'
while buy_more:
    if buy_more not in 'YyNn': 
        print("Please enter (Y or N) only. ")
        buy_more = input("Do you wish to choose some more items? (Y or N) ")

   #loopback and let users to buy an additional item
    while buy_more in "Yy":
        query = int(input("Enter the code number of the item you want to get: "))
        print(items[query][0], "will cost you", "{:.2f}".format(items[query][1]/100),"dollars")
        shopping_list[query] = [items[query][0],items[query][1]]
        print("Nice! Please choose one more item.")
        buy_more = input("Do you wish to choose some more items? (Y or N) ")

        #Continue to the transaction process
    if buy_more in "Nn":
        print("Continue to transaction process. ")
        break
        
print(shopping_list)
```